# How to apply pagination by _id while filtering _id by date range

Tags: java, mongodb, thymeleaf

Since ObjectId contains datetime so i was using _id to filter records by date range.

like

```
{
 "_id" : { 
           "$gte" :  ObjectId("5aeed1be0000000000000000"),
           "$lte" :  ObjectId("5aeed1be0000000000000000"),
         }
}
```

Now i would like to apply pagination too by _id for fast pagination i am preventing the use of skip.

is that possible for me to add another $gte or $lte filter on _id field.

thanks.

Comment: You can get rid of `skip()` but you're still going to `limit()`. So basically keep track of the last `_id` seen on the `limit()` boundary. More details on the referenced question, but it's a bit easier when you're using `_id` as the range already since you would be ( and should be ) sorting on that same field anyway. It just means advancing the `$gt` value for `_id` to the last seen on each page.

Comment: I have not misunderstood anything. Please read the referenced answer and learn something. You keep the last `_id` value from the page and use it as the new starting point in the range. The process for paging without skip is explained with detail on the provided linked answer.

Comment: john is correct this question is not a duplicate.

Comment: @coolcool It's a duplicate. You create a range starting at one ObjectId value representing a date and ending at another ObjectId for the end date. You take a page with a limit, you then start your next range with `$gt` starting at the last seen _id`. Which is exactly what the linked answers say.